# Ошибка при получении страницы retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Пытаюсь получить страницу при помощи simple_html_dom и получаю ошибку:

> com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:
>   retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 404 Not Found

Подключила заголовки при отправке запроса, куки.. такой же результат. 
При вводе ссылки в браузер - страница нормально отображается.

С чем может быть связана эта ошибка?

Comment: А код не хотите показать?

Comment: HTTP 404 Not Found означает что такой страницы не существует